# Laravel 5.1 - Mail Attachments - fopen(...) failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5.1

When I try to send an email message with an attachment using `Mail::later` I get this error:

> `fopen(../public/Asesorias/a.txt)`: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

This is my code:

```
Mail::later(5, 'emails.test', ['testVar' => 'hello'], function ($message){
  $message->to('someaddress@hotmail.com', 'Someone');
  $message->subject('Hello');
  $message->attach('../public/Asesorias/a.txt');
});
```

I know this must be a silly question, but I’ve tried to change the file path and I can’t find a solution.

When I try to send an email message with an attachment using `Mail::send`, it works perfectly:

```
Mail::send('emails.test', ['testVar' => 'hello'], function ($message){
  $message->to('someaddress@hotmail.com', 'Someone');
  $message->subject('Hello');
  $message->attach('../public/Asesorias/a.txt');
});
```

This is my file path: `ProjectName\public\Asesorias\a.txt`

PS: In my actual code I use real email addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `public_path()` helper when building the file path:

```
$message->attach(public_path('Asesorias/a.txt'));
```

Comment: @JosephSilber Appreciate the edit, had no idea it supported that!